# Несколько функций main

Tags: c++, c++17, main

Легален ли следующий код с точки зрения стандарта?

```
#include <iostream>


int main() {
    std::cout << "main\n";
}

#define main not_main

int main() {
    std::cout << "not main\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Все комментаторы говорят, что да, но почему тогда [тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function) написано

> It cannot be predefined and cannot be overloaded: effectively, the
>   name main in the global namespace is reserved for functions

?

Comment: Он-то легален, но... Ну, типа ложку в рот из-под ноги нести, примерно так. Можно? Можно. Но зачем?...

Comment: Я имею в виду легальность с точки зрения стандарта

Comment: За что минусы??

Comment: Всё с порядке. В Си таким способом реализуют принцип пространства имён. В плюсах можно и так : `namespace { main(){}}`

Comment: Приведенный код содержит только одну функцию `main`. Никаких нарушений из цитаты в нем нет. @AlexGlebe *"В Си таким способом реализуют принцип пространства имён."* - это дичь какая-то

Comment: Обновил вопрос...

Comment: @VTT "predefined" не подразумевает pre`#define`d?

Comment: Предопределённый это как `int main();` где-то там.

Comment: Нет, predefined тут означает, что реализация не может самостоятельно предоставлять `main`.

Comment: @koko, тут скорее проблема перевода. *predefined* здесь означает *определенная заранее*. Например, в любой единице трансляции макро константы `__FILE__` или, например, `__STDC__` как раз являются *predefined*.

Answer (score 2):

Вы путаете уровень процессора (компилятора) и препроцессора (предкомпилятора). Данные понятия нельзя смешивать, иначе это приводит к "логической нестыковке".
  Вначале код проходит стадию препроцессора, где расшифровуются все принятые макросы - я их назову сокращения. И уже расшифрованый код компилируется, т.е. **код легален, в коде обьявлено две функции c разными именами**. Одна обьявлена main, а другая not_main с помошью макроса ("сокращения") main. Создайте map-файл - и увидите что функции две. На время прохождения препроцессором участка от #define до #undefine макрос будет иметь силу, но это не означает что компилятор получит два одинаковых названия. У компилятора линкера и других инструментов будет два разных имени.

Кстати, если вы из настоящего `main` (или другого места программы) не вызовете "подставной", то код второго никогда не выполнится, а вызвать его прийдется или через реальное имя, или прийдется использовать подставное (нужно догадаться как).

Рассмотрим на кошечках. Давайте договоримся что собака означает кошка. А потом вы говорите что "все собаки кошки" (которые до уговора) - это неверное суждение. "Откройте толковый словарь, там неправильно написано про собак" - тоже неверное суждение. Кошка равно собака - лишь на время действия уговора, но даже при этом она по-сути не становится собакой. Просто мы на время решили так условиться. Кто не видит что "условились" может сразу не понять в чём дело. Вот примерно так работают макросы на данном примере.

*В справке не написано потому что...* Поскольку препроцессор работает отдельно от компилятора, то считается что 1) его работу вы или знаете и понимаете, поскольку если на каждой странице напоминать что существует препроцессор, и очень важно понимать как он работает - это будет достаточно громоздко 2) что тот кто не знает препроцессор не использует его. Поэтому часто использование `#define` считается плохим тоном. Точнее плохой тон - использовать его просто-так там где это не нужно. Использование макросов может сбивать с толку анализаторы подстветку синтаксиза, и людей читающих ваш код.

Цель препроцессора - несколько иная. Сделать код более читабельным, объеденять большие куски кода вместе, можно делать свёртки кода, можно следитить за версионностью, используя макросы достигают кросс-платформенности, деление на дебаг-релиз и возможно некоторые другие нестандартные вещи. Софт не запрещает использовать препроцессор для запутывания кода, то что сделали вы.

Фраза *the name main in the global namespace is reserved for functions* - означает что main глобального пространства имен зарезервирована как точка входа в программу, и если вы её обьявите в другом пространстве имен (namespace) - то она не будет выполнять ф-цию точки входа. Просто даное предложение невозможно "дословно" слово-в-слово перевести.

Учасник VTT верно заметил, что "predefined" не подразумевает pre + "#defined". Думаю что текст выше обьясняет почему.

Полезные ссылки: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%A1%D0%B8

Comment: Точнее сказано в спецификайии: The function main shall not be used within a program. The linkage (3.5) of main is implementation-defined. A program that defines main as deleted or that declares main to be inline, static, or constexpr is illformed. **The name main is not otherwise reserved.** [ Example: member functions, classes, and numerations can be called main, as can entities in other namespaces. —end example ]